# Why does my Merge fail? map() find() [javascript]

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, merge, array-map

I keep having issues when trying to merge data using map() and find() to merge two arrays of objects, often receiving something along the lines of `TypeError: Cannot read property 'customSku' of null`

I'm selecting the object keys correctly, so I'm wondering if there is something inherently wrong with the way I am trying to do this as sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

My latest attempt looks like:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const binLocations = require("../data/json/locations.json");
const opsuiteItems = require('../data/json/items.json')

const merged = binLocations.map((item) => {
  itm = opsuiteItems.find((itm) => itm.customSku === item.customSku)
  if (itm) {
    return {
      itemID: item.itemID,
      customSku: itm.customSku,
      defaultCost: itm.vendorCost,
      tag: item.binLocation 
    }
  }
})
```

With data like so:

```
//opsuiteItems
{
    "active": true,
    "customSku": "H2442",
    "vendorCost": "19",
  }

// binLocations
{
    "itemID": "2840",
    "customSku": "H2442",
    "binLocation": "G"
  }
```

Is it an issue with the amount of data or?

Comment: Are both arrays populated from an async action ? From the error description, I'd say you are not awaiting the arrays to have values, and one of them is empty

Comment: it clearly tells that you do not have any thing mathing the current item in the opsuiteItems array.

Comment: _"if there is something inherently wrong with the way I am trying to do this"_ - If you're not going to return something for every element in an array you shouldn't be using `.map()`.

Comment: @nip They are imported from a file using require.

Comment: @Andreas I did not know that. What should I be doing instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

```
const merged = binLocations.filter((item) => {
  return item != null && opsuiteItems.findIndex((opItem) => opItem.customSku === item.customSku) >= 0;
}).map((item) => {
  const itm = opsuiteItems.find((itm) => itm.customSku === item.customSku)
  if (itm) {
    return {
      itemID: item.itemID,
      customSku: itm.customSku,
      defaultCost: itm.vendorCost,
      tag: item.binLocation 
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: what are the issues?

Comment: Now, the code is updated and the problem was additional ')'. Now try again.

Comment: Yeah I spotted that and removed it.

js:21 itm = opsuiteItems.find((itm) => itm.customSku === item.customSku)
TypeError: Cannot read property 'customSku' of null.

It behaves as though item.customSku doesn't exist.

Comment: It is missed to define the variable like `const itm`

Comment: That still doesn't work, your code looks like it should handle if there is a customSku missing though right?

Comment: yes, right. Can you give me some of your test data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219218/discussion-between-darryl-morley-and-derek-w).

Answer (score 2):

`.map` expects something to be returned always. Use `forEach` to loop through and do conditional merging

```
const merged = [];

binLocations.forEach(item => {
  const match = item && opsuiteItems.find(el => el.customSku === item.customSku);

  if (match) {
    merged.push({
      itemID: item.itemID,
      customSku: item.customSku,
      defaultCost: match.vendorCost,
      tag: item.binLocation 
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: It still fails on item.customSku as if item.customSku doesn't exist. Although it definitely does.

Comment: Are you able to console log the data before if block `console.log(item, itm);`?

Comment: It logs some... maybe the data is missing a customSku somewhere, although it definitely should not.

Comment: Not sure if the `itm` is being modified somewhere outside? Because `.find` result `undefined` not `null`. Try using different variable name. Updating my answer. Please check @DarrylMorley

Comment: Still fails, is it that the data is not applied in full to the variable on the require import when the code is run, that's the only thing I can think of?

Comment: If you are able to console log `binLocations` and `opsuiteItems` properly after **import** and there are no typos in variable name/object key values then the above code should work. Take a little coffee ☕ break and come back and check it. You can find out that typo/import issue. Good luck 

Comment: Yeah they both console.log, haha good idea . Thanks for the help.

Comment: Lol... You have `null` in array `data`. That's the reason. Got it. 

Comment:    Yeah I do 

Comment: Updated my answer just to make sure. Thanks for confirming anyhow. Just confirm if the above one also works as expected if you have sometime. Ignore otherwise.